# VUEjs template computed array order

Tags: arrays, sorting, templates, vue.js

I have a VUE template, then gets an array from an API, let's say it's a country list.

now depending on an ID I receive I need to reorder this array....

It could look like this:

```
Vue.component('select-list', {
template: '#select_list',
props: ['id', 'label', 'selected', 'list'],
computed: {
    // a computed getter
    computedList: function () {

        // I think I need to reorder the array (list) in here?

    }
}});
```

my template looks like this:

```
<template id="select_list">
<div class="nfw-row">
    <label :for="id">{{ label }}</label>
    <div>
        <select :name="id" :id="id" v-model="selected">
            <option value="">Please select...</option>
            <option :value="list_item" v-for="list_item in computedList">{{ list_item.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

So am I on the right track if I need to order my list? Let's say that the entries 5, 7, 6 and 10 are supposed to be ordered at the top of my array...

Comment: You're on the right track, yes. What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the way to do this. You can use something like lodash:

```
computed: {
    computedList: function () {     
      return _.sortBy(this.list, [function(o) { return o.id; }]);
    }
}});
```